# 401 rest_forbidden error when using the WordPress REST API to edit a post

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, routes, put

I'm building a headless WordPress CMS with a front end React JS application. I'm currently developing locally using Local by Flywheel with web server set to Apache for WordPress (http://localhost:10058/) and create-react-app to spin up the React app (http://localhost:3000/). I'm having difficulty using the WordPress REST API to edit existing posts.

I'm pretty new to this side of development and feel somewhat out of my depth. I'm aware that there may be really obvious things I'm missing but I'd appreciate any help with this.

My .htaccess file in WordPress is set up like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
</IfModule>
```

The extra lines are inserted at the bidding of the JWT Authentication for WP-API. I've also added CORS permissions in wp-config.php like so:

```
/** CORS */
define('JWT_AUTH_CORS_ENABLE', true);
```

As well as the requisite secret key required by the plugin.

I've set up the custom route in WordPress like so:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'rmgImageRoute');

function rmgImageRoute () {

 // register GET and call back here   

  register_rest_route('rmg/v1', '/edit/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods' => 'PUT',
    'callback' => 'rmgEditMeta',
    'args' => array(
      'id' => array(
        'validate_callback' => function ($param, $request, $key) {
          return is_numeric($param);
        }
      )
    ),
    'permission_callback' => function () {
      return current_user_can('edit_posts');
    }
  ));  
}
```

with the following callback function:

```
function rmgEditMeta($request) {
  $id = $request->get_param('id');
  $title = $request->get_param('title');
  $content = $request->get_param('content');
  $contains_people = $request->get_param('contains_people');

  $post_id = wp_update_post(array(
    'ID' => $id,
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_content' => $content,
    'meta_input' => array(
      'contains_people' => $contains_people
    )
  ));

  if ($post_id) {
    return array('success' => true, 'post_id' => $post_id);
  } else {
    return array('success' => false);
  }
}
```

I'm testing using Postman and the RESTer Chrome extension and with the set up as described and hitting the following endpoint: http://localhost:10058/wp-json/rmg/v1/edit/211 (post 211 does exist, I've checked), with the following json in the request body:

```
{
  "title": "New Title",
  "content": "New Content",
  "contains_people": true
}.
```

However, this returns the error:

```
{
    "code": "rest_forbidden",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

If I switch off the JWT authentication plugin I get the same response.

Does anyone have any ideas? I've tried the approach above and have additionally tried using npm jsonwebtokens package and similar but these seem to cause the react app to crash due to the webpack set up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're not passing a valid nonce with your request (you didn't say whether you did) then the REST API will respond with a 403 error (Forbidden). Check the JWT documentation, it should tell you how to get a valid nonce so you can use it with your PUT requests.

Comment: Thanks - like I say, new to this and didn't know that was required. Will look into it.

Comment: Don't sweat it, I'm not criticizing you or anything like that :P It is required because, otherwise, anyone would be able to create posts on your site otherwise which -as you can imagine- wouldn't be a good thing.

Comment: Lol - no, got it and I didn't think that you were - it's just giving me a complete mare as I'm having to learn this as I go and no one else in the company even knows what I'm talking about(!)

Comment: Yeah, we've all been there. It gets better as you gain experience, I promise. Anyways, have a look at the documentation, keep tinkering, we're all still here if you need help.

Comment: Got it sort of working and also rediscovered my original account which I thought I'd lost. I've asked a related question entitled: "Nonce generated in WordPress route function working but returns "invalid nonce" when defined in wp-config.php" - if interested take a look.